# Position of neither.....nor

Tags: conjunctions, exam-questions

> A. She **neither** cares for gold **nor** silver
>
> B. She cares **neither** for gold **nor** for silver.
>
> C. She cares for **neither** gold **nor** silver.

The given answer is **A.**

Does the same part of speech is required after **"neither"** and **"nor"**. Why are other options incorrect?

Comment: I hope the question was "which sentence contains an error?"

Comment: They are not incorrect, just different ways of constructing the sentence.

Comment: C sounds most correct to me, A sounds very wrong, and B sounds okay.